# Insert into new table with userId column for all users from existing users table

Tags: sql, insert

I have `user_settings` table with two columns, `userId` and `value` which is currently empty but have another `users` table and now I need to add migration with query which should popuplate `user_settings` table for all users with some default value for `value` column.
I began with `INSERT INTO "user_settings" ("userId", "value") VALUES ($1, $2)` and got stuck. How to loop all `id's` from `users` table and fill this `user_settings` table with some default value...

Comment: Knowing the schema of the `users` table and which database system you are using would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need to 'loop' through the rows in `users`, as you can easily achieve this using an `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) like this:

```
SET @default = 'your_settings';

INSERT INTO `user_settings` (
  `userId`,
  `value`
) 
SELECT
  id,
  @default
FROM
  users
```

Suppose you are using a DBMS that supports triggers, you could also add a trigger to insert default settings upon inserting new records in `users`.
In MySQL it might look something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_user_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON 
  users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_settings (
      userId,
      value
    ) 
    VALUES (
      NEW.id,
      'your_settings'
    );
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

(Assuming the primary key on `users` table is called `id`.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some syntax elements here because you didn't say which database system you are using.

```sql
INSERT INTO "user_settings" ("userId", "value")
SELECT DISTINCT "userId", 'defaultvalue'
FROM "users"
```

To learn more, read training materials such as those found at:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp